# Nested div with overflow not working

Tags: css, html, nested

When I put a scrolling `div` (i.e. `<div style="width:200;height:200;overflow-y:scroll;">`) inside of another `div` that has an `overflow` attribute it treats the second `div` like I don't have dimensions set (height 200 and width 200). The scroll bar on the right shows up but it wont work because every time I add content the div just drops instead of making it scroll.

First divs css:

```
#slide1_container 
{
        width:976px;
        height:520px;
        overflow:hidden;
        position:relative;
        margin:0 auto;
    }
```

Nested div:

```
overflow-y:scroll;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the `px` on the dimensions in your div's inline styles.

```
<div style="width:200;height:200;overflow-y:scroll;">
```

Should be

```
<div style="width:200px;height:200px;overflow-y:scroll;">
```

Comment: The simplest thing...ever.....i have px on everything except that one small thing, even when I posted my actual code nobody got it Thankyou!! I will check it as the answer in 10 minutes